# Nodejs Express simple import js file router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

how to import the user.json json file into my user.js ? when i type / user the json should be displayed? new version of node I don't understand

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import usersRoutes from './routes/users.js';

const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/users', usersRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

**user.js**

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', (res, req) => {
    res.send();
});

export default router;
```

[image]

Comment: what exactly it is the error? note that user.json is different than user.js

Answer (score 1):

```
import express from 'express';
import userJSON from '../user.json' // < ------- here
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', (res, req) => {
    res.send();
});

export default router;
```

Comment: i have this error: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" when i try localhost:5000/users

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the version you are using you either has to use babel or include the --experimental-json-modules flag for the module to work. ** node v.14 does not need anything.

node --experimental-json-modules about.js

```
import express from 'express';
import userfile from '../user.json' // import the json file
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', (res, req) => {
    res.send(userfile);  //this line sends the json
});

export default router;
```

Comment: same errors: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" for C:\Users\33680\Documents\Developpement\Angular\api\user.json

Comment: Which node are you using? Are you using babel ?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial That it is what I call a bug.

Comment: normally, I post answers base on latest version, and advise if user have further errors. Thanks for the post update

Answer (score 1):

Instead use the fs module:

```js
const user = require('fs').readFileSync('../user.json', 'utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply:

```
import express from 'express';
import user from '../user'; // <---- Don't need even the .json extension.
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', (res, req) => {
    res.send(user);
});

export default router;
```